# Condition to parse the CSV file only when number of columns exceeds by 1

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read data from CSV file that exists in S3 bucket using pandas. However, sometimes sometimes CSV files exists with just 1 column which is something I dont want to parse. I only want to parse the CSV in which there is more than 1 column. Can anyone tell me the condition to check which says if number of columns > 1, then only parse the file, else exit the loop. 
Below is the code I am trying.

```
body = csv_obj['Body']
csv_string = body.read().decode('utf-8-sig')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string),usecols = [3,4,6])
```

Below is the second code I tried but got error: `File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from io import StringIO # Python 3.x


s3_client = session.client("s3")
s3_resource = session.resource("s3")
csv_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="XXXX", Key="XXXXXXYYY.csv")
body = csv_obj['Body']
csv_string = body.read().decode('utf-8-sig')                        
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), nrows = 10)
if len(df.columns) > 1:
     df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string),usecols = [3,4,6])
     Products_list = df.values.tolist()
     Products_list = str(Products_list)
     print(Products_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
import pandas as pd

# put your scv file instead of following url
url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cs109/2014_data/master/countries.csv"
c = pd.read_csv(url)

if len(c.count()) > 1:
  # Your code
  print("Enjoy dude :)")
```

Comment: I am accessing CSV file from my S3 bucket. What changes should I make to make it work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Parse all files, and them check for `if len(df.columns) > 1`.

If the file is large, you can test for number of columns by reading limited number of rows with `read_csv(nrows=N)` parameter, and if test for number of columns succeeds, read the file in whole again.

I am not sure what your loop code looks like, here is a simple example, which returns nothing if number of columns is equal to 1:

```
body = csv_obj['Body']
csv_string = body.read().decode('utf-8-sig')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string), nrows=10)
if len(df.columns) > 1:
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string),usecols = [3,4,6])
else:
    return
```

Comment: I am getting error in line `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string),usecols = [3,4,6])` on the first place even if a try to parse. Since I am giving column numbers here

Comment: Skip the `usecols` parameter for now. After checking of number of columns succeds, just use `df = df.iloc[:, [3,4,6]]` to subset columns needed.

Comment: could you please rewrite my code snippet to show. I guess I am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: could you have a look at the code I shared in the original question. It gives me error `File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

Comment: I think if it doesn't have an entry for each row, it is not really a CSV file and might need a different tool to read in. Do all the lines have the same number of commas? Perhaps you want to just process the file line by line, then choose to pass/reject each line based on number of results returned.